# external auditory canal

Tags: word-usage

Which one of these two (**external auditory canal**/ **external part of ear canal**) works in the following sentence?

> *There is a variety of types of hearing protection devices including ear muffs which completely cover the ear and earplugs which are inserted in the **external part of ear canal**/**external auditory canal**.*

Thanks!

Comment: [What does EAC stand for?](https://www.allacronyms.com/_medical/EAC/External_Auditory_Canal) But this is really about domain-specific terminology, not the use of English by ordinary native speakers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "external auditory canal" is a term of art: only someone with expert anatomical knowledge can say whether experts would regard "external part of the ear canal" as synonymous.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend who your audience is, but

> ear canal

might be a better choice, as it is more straightforward and less *jargon*, and more people will easily understand what you are saying

[image]